# Assigning list values to the parameter

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have the following list:

```
lst = [(A,[1,2,3,4]), (B, [1,2,3,5]). (C, [4,5,7,6])]
```

I would like to split the list such that all the x (should be str) values contain A, B, C, D and Y( should be int) contains [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,5], [4,5,7,6]. Desired output:

```
print(x)
A, B, C, D
print(y)
[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,5], [4,5,7,6]
```

What I tried so far?

```
x,y=[(a,b) for a, b in zip(lst[0], lst[1])])]
```

This does not store the value of x and y. How do I do that?

Comment: Check `x, y = zip(*lst) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using list comprehension with zip,

```
x,y = zip(*[(item[0], item[1]) for item in lst])
```

Answer (score 5):

One liner:

```
x, y = zip(*lst)
```

Example:

```
lst = [('A',[1,2,3,4]), ('B', [1,2,3,5]), ('C', [4,5,7,6])]
x, y = zip(*lst)
print(x)  # Out: ('A', 'B', 'C')
print(y)  # Out: ([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 5], [4, 5, 7, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension -

```
>>> lst = [('A',[1,2,3,4]), ('B', [1,2,3,5]), ('C', [4,5,7,6])]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> x = [val[0] for val in lst]
>>> x
['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> y = [val[1] for val in lst]
>>> y
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 5], [4, 5, 7, 6]]
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, is it possible to combine both X and Y in one line?

Answer (score 0):

If you must have it in one line you could also do

```
x,y = [[v[i] for v in lst] for i in (0,1)]
```

but I'm not sure it is an improvement over something slightly longer and clearer.